# Is there a proof for the following series to diverge/converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was wondering weather the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\tan(n)} {n^b}$$
diverges or converges whenever $b \geq 1$ is an integer. Does anyone have a proof for either statement? Does it converge for some positive integers but not for others? In that case, which are they?

Comment: It is closely related to the irrationality measure $\mu$ of $\pi$, as $\mu$ determines the speed at which $\tan n$ grows. Indeed, it is well-known that $\mu < \infty$, so that the series converges for large $b$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470527/does-the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac-tan-nn2-converge

Comment: @dani_s Thanks, this one was linked:
http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2690793?uid=3737512&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21100858189611

I dont feel like signing up in order to read the paper, do you know if the paper is relevant? In that case, can it be found somewhere else?

Comment: @sos440, do you have any evidence for the series to converge for large $b$? How large?

Comment: @GeorgeMouselli No I don't know, the answer to the question seems to be far from trivial though

Comment: Any $b > \mu(\pi^{-1}$$ works.

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous post.

Comment: get a look here : http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.5431&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The series certainly diverges for $b=1$ and converges for $b\ge 8$, as shown in [this article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.5431&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Sam Coskey.  Moreover, it "stays very small for a very long time" when $b=2$.

In one of the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159438/prove-the-convergence-divergence-of-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac-tank), it is argued that the series will converge if $b > \mu(\pi^{-1})$, where $\mu$ is the [irrationality measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrationality_measure#Irrationality_measure).  The irrationality measure of $1/\pi$ is the same as the irrationality measure of $\pi$, which has recently received an improved upper bound of $7.6063$ (Salikhov 2008; see [MathWorld's article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) for full reference).  While this argument reproduces the already-known result (convergence for $b\ge 8$), it shows that a tighter upper bound on $\mu(\pi)$ would immediately imply convergence for smaller values of $b$.