# Irrationality measure.

Tags: irrational-numbers

I would like someone to give me a definition of what irrationality measure is, I have stumbled over several definitions which may be equivalent but as I lack understanding I cant see this correlation. So I am looking for a definition and also a brief explanation of what it really tells us, is it something that tells us "how irrational" a number is?

I have decided to study this subject a little more since it was part of the answer to my question in this thread: [Is there a proof for the following series to diverge/converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695570/is-there-a-proof-for-the-following-series-to-diverge-converge) (I dont know if my tags are ok)

Comment: Can you post some of the proposed definitions so we can evaluate them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one has given an answer, I'll offer some suggestions. However, this isn't something I know all that much about, despite the fact that I somehow managed to answer a recent question on the topic: [Does every normal number have irrationality measure $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615948/does-every-normal-number-have-irrationality-measure-2).

I don't know your background, so I'll start low and end high.

A really nice and elementary place to begin reading about underlying ideas is with Chapters 6 and 7 in Ivan Niven's [**Numbers: Rational and Irrational**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883856018). After this, maybe look over Chapter XI in Hardy/Wright's [**An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199219869). This should get you far enough to have a reasonable sense of what the topic is about, and where you go next depends a lot on what your mathematical background is.

Some advanced references that seem worth looking at include the following:

[**Approximation by Algebraic Numbers**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521823293) by Yann Bugeaud

[**Transcendental Number Theory**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052139791X) by Alan Baker (Chapter 8)

[**Making Transcendence Transparent**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387214445) by Burger/Tubbs (Chapter 6).