# Good monograph/textbook for modern research on convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, reference-request

I have a reasonable background in undergraduate real analysis, and I am very interested in questions concerning the convergence of series, and also how this relates to irrationality measure. I would like to know what the current state of modern research on convergence is, my end goal being to fully understand all of the research in this area. I have encountered a few papers online that contain very interesting results that establish the convergence of, or convergence tests for, a wider class of series (relaxations of the monotonicity requirement in the integral test, for example), and have seen a few things about how the convergence of series can relate to irrationality measure. Unfortunately, I have found that I generally do not have the prerequisites for reading these papers, and each one references so many others that I feel I don't have any grasp of what the overall research on the subject looks like. So, are there any good monographs or textbooks I can read to gain an understanding of modern research on the convergence of series?

To clarify, I already have an undergraduate-level education in real analysis, so I'm not looking for straight analysis textbooks, unless they have a heavy emphasis on convergence of series.

Comment: Regarding convergence and irrationality measure: is the [Flint Hills series](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5100) what you had in mind?

Comment: The Theory and Application of Infinite Series might be a good place to start.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes; I have seen a paper that proves that its convergence implies that the irrationality measure of pi is less than or equal to 2.5, and I saw an MO answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282259/is-the-series-sum-n-sin-nn-n-convergent/282290#282290) that mentions the irrationality measure of pi in the proof of the convergence of a series

Comment: Try the google search ["thesis" + "irrationality measure" + "series"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thesis%22+%22irrationality+measure%22+%22series%22). Other than books dealing more generally with transcendental numbers, I don't think you'll find any published books having a nontrivial focus on what you're asking about, but perhaps some Ph.D. or Masters theses might have this. There might also be some expository/survey papers, but you'd likely find those already cited in literature you know about, but probably not citations to theses, hence my suggested google search.

Comment: Incidentally, when I said "other than books dealing more generally with transcendental numbers", what I had in mind were books such as those I gave in my answer to [Irrationality measure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/855823/13130)