# Looking for good book on transcendental number theory

Tags: reference-request, transcendental-numbers

I'm looking for advanced text book and more friendly text, especially in the advanced ones. One thing in particular that I'm looking for is a geometric approach to the theory, since I was unable to find one, but anything related to transcendental number theory will be welcome.

Oh, also an algebraic geometry approach or category theory approach will be very useful for my project.

PS: sorry for the english, it's not my main language.

Comment: Some standard texts are listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/855823/13130). In addition to those, see [**Transcendental Numbers**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3110115689) by Andrei Borisovich Shidlovskii, which is notable for its extensive discussion of [$E$-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-function). However, these texts are more analysis-oriented than algebraic-oriented. For a more algebraic-oriented text, maybe [**Introduction to Transcendental Numbers**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002RZ783I) by Serge Lang, although this might be a bit dated now.

Comment: Thanks deeply, I'm actualy like analysis, so this probably gonna be fun.

Answer (score 1):

Transcendental Numbers  by Carl Ludwig Siegel